# How to formulate this lemma into a first order symbolic statement? (Finite Choice Lemma - Tao Analysis I)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Here is a lemma that I have been tasked to prove. I am not interested in how to carry out this proof. Instead, **I want to formally formulate the first order symbolic sentence that encodes the lemma**. The lemma reads as follows:

> ***Let $n \geq 1$ be a natural number, and for each natural number $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $X_i$ be a non-empty set***. Then there exists an $n$-tuple $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ such that $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$.

I am particularly interested in how one **encodes the antecedent** of this conditional (what I have bolded in the above highlighted lemma). For brevity, I am going to refer to the consequent (i.e. "then there exists an $n$ -tuple...") as $\exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big)$.

The only thing I can really think to do is the following:

$\forall n, X_1 \Big(\big(n \in \mathbb N \land n = 1 \land X_1 \neq\emptyset\big) \rightarrow \exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big) \Big)$

$\forall n, X_1, X_2 \Big(\big(n \in \mathbb N \land n = 2 \land X_1 \neq\emptyset \land X_2 \neq \emptyset \big) \rightarrow \exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big) \Big)$

$\forall n, X_1, X_2, X_3 \Big(\big(n \in \mathbb N \land n = 3 \land X_1 \neq\emptyset \land X_2 \neq \emptyset \land X_3 \neq \emptyset \big) \rightarrow  \exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big) \Big)$

$...$

Edit:

After reading the below comments, I wonder if this is a better approach?

$\forall n, X \bigg(\Big( n \in N \land n \geq 1 \land \text{dom}(X) = \{i:1 \leq i \leq n \} \land \forall k \big(1 \leq k \leq n \implies X(k) \neq \emptyset\big)\Big) \implies \exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big)\bigg)$

I probably need to specify that $i$ and $k$ are restricted to $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set theory generally gives us the means to package complicated data into a single object. Ordered tuples and functions are the first things that come to mind.

Notice in the language of first order set theory, we don't have any "subscripting"... this is purely stuff that we do for our own convenience. When we say "for each $i \le n,$ let $X_i$ be a nonempty set", what is actually going on under the hood is we are defining a function:

> $X$ is a function whose domain is the natural numbers $\le n$ and whose range contains only nonempty sets.

So we might more accurately write $X(i)$ rather than $X_i.$ But that notation is still not part of the formal language. A much-more-attentive-to-the-microcopic-details, but still not fully unpacked version would be

> For every $x\in X,$ $x$ is an ordered pair such that the first component of $x$ is a natural number $\le n$ and the second component is a nonempty set. Furthermore, for each natural number $i\le n$, there is a unique $x\in X$ such that $i$ is the first component of $x$.

And for a given $i,$ the set $X_i$ would be defined as

> The second component of the unique element of $X$ whose first component is $i.$

So that's the premise... when we want to write the conclusion -- which I presume says there is a function $f$ such that $f(i)\in X_i$ for all $i$ -- in a similar extreme level of detail, we need to go through the same song and dance as above to say $f$ is a function with domain $i\le n$, and then just say

> For each $i\le n,$ the second component of the unique element of $f$ whose first component is $i$ is an element of the the second component of the unique element of $X$ whose first component is $i.$

---

On a side note, it can to massive confusion when we implicitly assume that the "subscripting" is something that somehow happens directly in the formal language. I've seen many-a-question where a student can't grasp how the axiom of choice is not trivially provable, with reasoning along the lines of

> Each set $X_i$ is nonempty, so for all $i$, $\exists x_i\in X_i.$ So just set $f(i) = x_i.$

This misses the point because the informal notation misleadingly implies that there is a ready-made element $x_i$ already "chosen". If you unpack what this is actually saying formally, you will see it *assumes* the axiom choice, rather than proving it.

Comment: I should add that this isn’t the only way to package it up. For instance can also use ordered tuples, which are usually implemented as nested ordered pairs. They strike me as much clumsier for these purposes, though, for instance you need to define a lot more things recursively.

Comment: thank you for the thorough response! The issue I am having is determining what the codomain of the function $X$ should be in the following notation: $\forall n, X \bigg(\Big( n \in N \land n \geq 1 \land X \in \{i:1 \leq i \leq n \} \rightarrow ? \land \forall k \big(1 \leq k \leq n \implies X(k) \neq \emptyset\big)\Big) \implies \phi(\chi)\bigg)$ Specifically, the "?" in the above statement.

Comment: The only codomain I can think of is the "universal set" minus the empty set...and because this is probably not allowed, I'm think that this notation is likely wrong.

Comment: @S.Cramer  $X\in \{i:1\le i \le n\}$ doesn't make any sense... you mean dom(X) = $\{i:1\le i \le n\}$, I think. Also not sure what you are getting at with the statement ? following an implication arrow. the part $\forall k \le n X(k)\ne \emptyset$ you concatenate after that says that the range consists of nonempty sets, which is the only thing you need to say about the range.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion with the notation that I am using for $X$. I am familiar with the idea that a function can belong to a particular mapping scheme...for example, I have seen $f \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: @S.Cramer Oh, I just parsed it. You are saying "$X$ is a function with domain $\{i:1\le i \le n\}$ and range ?". Why not just say "$X$ is a function with  domain $\{i:1\le i \le n\}$"? Like I said above, you have already said what you need to say about the range with the part that follows

Comment: ohhhh, that makes a lot of sense! Gotch ya gotch ya.

Comment: @S.Cramer Never seen that before. The usual notation is $f\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N\times \mathbb N}$ or $f\in {}^{\mathbb N\times \mathbb N}\mathbb N$ or $f:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I think I finally arrived at the correct antecedent then. Would you green light this? $\forall n, X \bigg(\Big( n \in N \land n \geq 1 \land \text{dom}(X) = \{i:1 \leq i \leq n \} \land \forall k \big(1 \leq k \leq n \implies X(k) \neq \emptyset\big)\Big) \implies \exists \chi \big(\phi(\chi)\big)\bigg)$

Comment: I probably need to specify that $i$ and $k$ are restricted to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes that expresses what you want, clearly enough to me. Don't think there is a right or wrong answer for whether you "need" to specify the restriction to $\mathbb N$... seems implied by $1\le k \le n$, and keep in mind we are still pretty far away the actual low-level formal language.

Comment: Oh, interesting. If you are willing, I’d love to see an “actual low-level” version of this...in hopes that I could take some insights away from it. Thanks for sticking with me through this. Very helpful and informative.

Comment: @S.Cramer It would be long and unreadable. I tried to give an outline of something a bit more low-level in the answer. (Note, just because I'm writing in English rather than symbols does not have much bearing at all on what "level" we're at. The point is I'm talking about more low-level concepts, e.g. the implementation of the function as collections of ordered pairs. Then we can take it to an even lower level by expanding out the concepts more, e.g. how an ordered pair is implemented in (say) the Kuratowski way: $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ and how to say "the first component" in terms of this.